# jQuery : Dynamic table - row index

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code which dynamically add html table columns. And these new columns  have 3 radios. And I want to select a single radio out of these 3 in each rows.

I am trying to find out the **table row index** so that I can add this to the radio id. But getting value **undefined** .

https://jsfiddle.net/jjayaraman/evo6kx0k/

**Problem** : 'Coz of this all radio has same ID and I can select only one of all the radios... not one for each row..

Here is my code

```js
$(document)
  .ready(
    function() {
      $("#addBtn")
        .click(
          function() {
            $("#myTable thead tr")
              .append(
                '<th colspan="3">New Header</th>')
            $('#myTable tbody tr')
              .append(
                '<td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + $('#myTable tr').rowIndex + ' value="Y"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + $('#myTable tr').rowIndex + ' value="N"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + $('#myTable tr').rowIndex + ' value="NA">')
          });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <table border="1" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>R1 Column1</td>
        <td>R1 Column2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R2 Column1</td>
        <td>R2 Column2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R3 Column1</td>
        <td>R3 Column2</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>
  <input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add column">

</form>
```

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: @lal added link for fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually append the content to each row since the `append` function doesn't reevaluate the expression for each item. `each` does...

```js
$(document)
  .ready(
    function() {
      $("#addBtn")
        .click(
          function() {
            $("#myTable thead tr")
              .append(
                '<th colspan="3">New Header</th>')
            $('#myTable tbody tr')
              .each(function(i) {
                $(this).append(
                  '<td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + i + ' value="Y"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + i + ' value="N"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + i + ' value="NA">')
              })
          });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <table border="1" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>R1 Column1</td>
        <td>R1 Column2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R2 Column1</td>
        <td>R2 Column2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R3 Column1</td>
        <td>R3 Column2</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>
  <input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add column">

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

`rowIndex` is a DOM property, it can't be used on a jQuery object. Also, `$("#myTable tr")` returns a collection of all the rows, so the index won't be just the row that you're appending to.

Instead of supplying HTML directly in the `.append()` call, you can give it a function. This will then be called for each element in the collection (similar to calling `.append()` within `.each()`), and its return value will be appended.

You were also missing the closing `"` in the `name` attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
    $("#myTable thead tr").append('<th colspan="3">New Header</th>');
    $('#myTable tbody tr').append(function(i) {
      var name = 'interActivity' + i;
      return '<td><input type="radio" name="' + name + '" value="Y"></td><td><input type="radio" name="' + name + '" value="N"></td><td><input type="radio" name="' + name + '" value="NA">';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <table border="1" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>R1 Column1</td>
        <td>R1 Column2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R2 Column1</td>
        <td>R2 Column2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R3 Column1</td>
        <td>R3 Column2</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>
  <input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add column">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each row to get the index and then append. This if you WANT to use .index() otherwise as other answers suggest you can just use the index generated from .each.

Something like this

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function(index, value){
  var index = $(this).index(); // or just index
  $(this).append('<td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + index + ' value="Y"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + index + ' value="N"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + index + ' value="NA">')
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#addBtn").click(function() {
          $("#myTable thead tr").append('<th colspan="3">New Header</th>')
          $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function(){
            var index =$(this).index();
            $(this).append('<td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + index + ' value="Y"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + index + ' value="N"></td><td><input type="radio" name="interActivity' + index + ' value="NA">')
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form>

      <table border="1" id="myTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Heading1</th>
            <th>Heading2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>R1 Column1</td>
            <td>R1 Column2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>R2 Column1</td>
            <td>R2 Column2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>R3 Column1</td>
            <td>R3 Column2</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

      <br> <input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add column">

    </form>


  </body>
</html>
```